# Do Visa Officer will check my employment status that I filled in previous and present DS-160 Form

Tags: usa

A year ago I filled a DS 160 for F-1 visa and in that I kept my job joining date was (10-Jan-2021. But, it is actually (10-Jan-2022). and without checked it I went to interview on July 2022. I said from past 6 months I'm working with xxxxx company. unfortunately, my visa got rejected( I don't know the exact reasons for rejection) but Now if I fill new DS 160 form can I corrected the year of joining in company? will visa officer know what I filled in my previous DS 160 form?

Hoping for an answer from someone who have knowledge about it.

Comment: > I don't know the exact reasons for rejection. Under what INA paragraph were you refused?

Comment: I’d imagine they will, but this time your employment contract will *match* what you enter in the form *and* if asked you should be able to explain the previous error

Comment: under (214-B) Section